# i want to load a json data to mysql database but it taking too much time

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin, bigdata

i want to store the json file data to mysql database but it is taking too much time.  The data is about 145K elements. I think bigdump.php is useful, but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: https://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage

Comment: What are you doing now to load data? And how much is too much time?

Comment: Are you storing the JSON in a single TEXT field?  In a JSON column?  As 145K fields spread across multiple rows and columns?  Something else?  How will you later access the JSON -- as a single JSON string?  Or by looking at individual fields?